# Resolving an URL with Java gives me the wrong encoded chars in URL

Tags: java, character-encoding, url-encoding

When I'm doing the following:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlAsString);
    //using proxy may increase latency
    HttpURLConnection hConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    // force no follow
    hConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    // the program doesn't care what the content actually is       
    hConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    // default is 0 => infinity waiting
    hConn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    hConn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    hConn.connect();
    int responseCode = hConn.getResponseCode();
    hConn.getInputStream().close();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        return urlAsString;

    String loc = hConn.getHeaderField("Location");
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM && loc != null)
        return loc.replaceAll(" ", "+");

} catch (Exception ex) {
}
return "";
```

for that url: http://bit.ly/gek1qK I'm getting

http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-downtime/twitter-redesignsâthen-everything-breaks/

which is wrong. Firefox resolves to

http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-downtime/twitter-redesigns%E2%80%94then-everything-breaks/

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [RFC 2616, section 2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2), HTTP header values should normally be encoded using ISO-8859-1.

Here, bit.ly is sending a bad response - the Location: header is encoded using UTF-8, so the em-dash character is represented by three separate bytes (0xe2, 0x80, 0x94).

`HttpURLConnection` decodes the bytes using ISO-8859-1 so they become three characters (`â` and two undefined characters), <s>but it looks as if you re-encode them using UTF-8 (producing 2 bytes per character, since all three have values >= 0x80) before applying URL-encoding</s>.

Firefox most likely treats the data as ISO-8859-1 throughout; the problem then cancels itself out when URL-encoding is applied later on.

You could do the same by URL-encoding the value returned by `getHeaderField()`; since the Unicode range U+0080 to U+00FF is identical to the ISO-8859-1 byte range 0x80-0xFF, the non-ASCII characters can be encoded by casting them to `int` values:

```
/**
 * Takes a URI that was decoded as ISO-8859-1 and applies percent-encoding
 * to non-ASCII characters. Workaround for broken origin servers that send
 * UTF-8 in the Location: header.
 */
static String encodeUriFromHeader(String uri) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(char ch : badLocation.toCharArray()) {
        if(ch < (char)128) {
            sb.append(ch);
        } else {
            // this is ONLY valid if the uri was decoded using ISO-8859-1
            sb.append(String.format("%%%02X", (int)ch));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to apply url encoding for the location?

Comment: BTW: I apply encoding by accident. I copied the url into the url bar of firefox and then pasted from there into this question. Firefox applied the encoding ... I fixed this in the post

Comment: @SimonJ so I should file a bug report to bit.ly or can this be fixed differently?

Comment: You can try :) I've updated the answer with a workaround in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks soo much!! I can confirm that this works even for more complicated examples like: http://bit.ly/gyFxfv

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. The difference is the m-Dash denoted differently in different encoding. So, If Firefox uses encoding other than what your program does, you will see different character.

Both are correct, in your case. It's just matter of encoding. In Java, you use UTF-8, which is [World Wide Web Consortium Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars); while it seems that what you see in FF is ISO-8859.

If you want to generate same result as Firefox in Java, try this:

```
System.out.print(URLEncoder.encode(loc.replace(" ", "+"), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

It will print what you see in Firefox. (obviously, it will encode `/` and `:` as well. But just to demonstrate)

Comment: It's actually the other way round. The incorrect one is encoded in ISO8859-1 (or CP1252) and the correct one is encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: @BalusC hmm... I did not get you.what I am saying is UTF-8 is the one recommended -- which is correct. FF might be using platform dependent encoding.

Comment: Hmmh, but why do I need to encode the url location at all? Isn't it already encoded?

Comment: Yes, this additional encoding does not work. But I think I should probably read the header somehow as ISO-8859-1 to get the correct location. How to do this.

Comment: hmmh, the hConn.getContentType() is text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: Character Encoding is NULL in this case. That's why probably Java uses UTF-8, And Firefox Western ISO-8859-1 (see Firefox > Options > Content > Advanced > Default Encoding). But I am not 100% solid on this. `hConn.getContentEncoding()` gives `null`. No Encoding specified.